# Distance between two nodes in circular linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

I want to find the distance between two nodes (number of node between them) in  a circular linked list.

Where nodal is :

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}nodal;

nodal *distance(nodal *start)
{
    int n1,n2,d1=0,d2=0,c=0;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nList is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nEnter the fist node element : ");
        scanf("%d",&n1);
        printf("\nEnter the second node element : ");
        scanf("%d",&n2);
        nodal *ptr=start;
        while(ptr->next!=start)
        {
            c++;
            if(ptr->data==n1)
            {
                d1=c;
            }
            if(ptr->data==n2)
            {
                d2=c;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The distance between two nodes is %d",(d2-d1));
    return start;
}
```

I doesn't give any output.

Also suppose if circular list contains following data :

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

And if I give input

> First node element as 9
>
> Second node element as 4

Then this algorithm won't work.
Any suggestions for the change ?

Comment: typo , you compare against n1 in both `if` statements

Comment: Still no output @JoshGreifer

Comment: In second condition you have a typo: must be *n2*.

Comment: What does mean *no output*? Program hangs?

Comment: Yes @0andriy it hangs

Comment: Ah, this crazy leading *\n* — never do this. Put them at the end of line in each *printf()* call including last one.

Comment: If it hangs the list is broken.

Comment: My algorithm was broken @0andriy . Got the answer from below thanks.

Comment: Not exactly. You have misconceptions with term *circular*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start counting when you find the first node and stop when you find the second one, something like:

```
int inc = 0, dist = 0;

if (n1 == n2) {
    return 0;
}
node = start;
while (node) {
    dist += inc;
    if ((node->data == n1) || (node->data == n2)) {
        if (inc++ == 1) return dist;
    }
    node = node->next;
    if (node == start) break;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of while(node) ? @KeineLust

Comment: `while (node)` = `while (node != NULL)`, do some task while the pointer points to some valid region different to`NULL`

Comment: Good solution, works for both circular and NULL terminated lists.

Comment: Here is a simpler version: `int inc = 0, dist = 0; node = start; while (node) { dist += inc; if ((node->data == n1) || (node->data == n2)) { if (inc++ == 1) return dist; } node = node->next; if (node == start) break; } return 0; }` The first test is questionable: what if the list has duplicate nodes?

Comment: Note also that the scan may find `n2` before `n1` and return a different distance, not necessarily smaller.  Probably not what is expected.

Comment: @chqrlie, good suggestion, edited. Maybe I am wrong, but it seems (based on the last point of the question) that the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @Vivank, as pointed by chqrlie: if the list allows duplicates you should skip the test `if (n1 == n2)` and store somewhere the first value found.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to go to the first element entered, in this process count will not be increased. Then start increasing to count until you reach the second element.

Code is below:

```
ptr=start;
while(ptr->data!=n1)
{
   ptr=ptr->next;
}
//---now we have reached the first number----

while(ptr->data!=n2)
{
  count++;
ptr=ptr->next;
}
```

Comment: Infinite loop if the circular list does not contain both nodes,

Comment: I just answered according to required test case,

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the test for the end of the list prevents you from testing the last node.
- you handle the case where `n1 == n2` by returning `0`, which may not be what is expected.
- the distance between `n1` and `n2` will be negative if `n2` appears before `n1`, which is incorrect: since the list is circular, if you keep scanning after `n1`, you will encounter `n2` at a positive distance at most after wrapping over the first node.

Here is an alternate solution:

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} nodal;

nodal *distance(nodal *start) {
    int n1, n2, d1 = 0, d2 = 0, length = 0;
    if (start == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nEnter the fist node element : ");
        if (scanf("%d", &n1) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return start;
        }
        printf("\nEnter the second node element : ");
        if (scanf("%d", &n2) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return start;
        }
        nodal *ptr = start;
        for (;;) {
            length++;
            if (ptr->data == n1 && !d1) {
                d1 = length;
            } else if (ptr->data == n2) {
                if (d1) {
                    d2 = length;
                    break;
                }
                if (!d2)
                    d2 = length;
            }
            ptr = ptr->next;
            if (ptr == start)
                break;
        }
    }
    if (d1 && d2) {
        int dist = d2 - d1;
        if (dist < 0)
            dist += length;
        printf("The distance between node(%d) and node(%d) is %d\n", d1, d2, dist);
    } else {
        if (d2)
            printf("node(%d) not found\n", d1);
        if (d1)
            printf("node(%d) not found\n", d2);
    }
    return start;
}
```